# GNU Linux "sort -g" can hang indefinitely when run on standard input (on Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, pipe, sort

The following command (on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=800000 bs=1 | od -An -t f4 -w4 | sponge | sort -g
```

Can hang indefinitely, with the GNU sort command taking 100% of the CPU. I cannot understand what causes this. However, it only happens when the file to sort is input from stdin

Comment: What is the question? I can't reproduce this on my debian system on a total of 3 runs. Does the `Can` mean sometimes it does hang indefinitely but usually does not? Capturing the input would allow for a useful reproduction case to be added to a bug report.

Comment: OK, now I have a `sponge` in the pipeline I have reproduction. So `cat sort.in |  sort -g | head` does not hang but `cat sort.in | sponge | sort -g | head` does. (No UUOC awards please, the use of cat and a pipe is deliberate). Running under strace suggests that it has not read all the input.

Comment: OK, looks like `sponge` was not a cause. Sometimes `cat sort.in | sort -g | wc -l` spins and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried using `sort --debug` to see what it's trying to do?

Comment: I have tried to use `sort --debug -g` and when it hangs there is no output. Also, the use of `sponge` is not required to reproduce the bug. It only helps to rule out potential issues with the commands piping the numbers into `sort`

Comment: FYI you don't need dd: `od </dev/urandom -N800000 -An -tf4 -w4 |...`

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly a bug.

It is caused by 'nan' showing up at a position that apparently is bad.

This works (100x bigger than your example but removes all nan's):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=80000000 bs=1 | od -An -t f4 -w4 | sponge | grep -v nan | time sort -g |tail
```

The bug can be provoked with:

```
yes nan | head -n128095 | timeout 5 sort -g
```

The crazy part is, that this works:

```
yes nan | head -n128095 > nan
timeout 5 sort -g < nan
timeout 5 sort -g nan
```

Will you do the bug reporting?

Comment: I reported the bug and it was fixed by Paul Eggert:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2022-05/msg00001.html
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/2f56f5a42033dc6db15d8963e54566f01fa0d61d